# Best Way To Create A Callback Function

Tags: javascript, function, callback

Is there a better way than this to create a callback function for some random function ?

```
var showObj = function(obj,callback) {
    return setTimeout(function () {
        if(opts.centerObj == true) {
            var cssProps = getProps(obj);
            obj.css(cssProps).fadeIn('slow');
        }
            else {
                obj.fadeIn('slow');
            }
        if(typeof callback == 'function') {
            callback.call(this);
        }
    }, 1500);
}
```

The callback function doesn't have any parameter when I utilize it, I only do like this:

```
showObj(obj,function(){

/* Some Callback Function */

});
```

Comment: So your question is whether there is a better way than passing an anonymous function to `showObj` or what?

Comment: What is wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: @Felix Kling,No, if my syntax is correct, the function is working fine ( the callback function ) if I call it, and also if there is another way to add / define a callback function to some random function.

Comment: @TJHeuvel, I think nothing, but isn't there a better way or do I need the `callback.call(this)` or can I simply do `callback.call()` ?

Comment: It seems your question is more about how to *invoke* the callback and not how to *create* it.

Comment: Well, sorry if I asked it the wrong way :) Also, I see that you keep editing the post title and remove what's before `|` and that too, so won't do that anymore, didn't knew it's a problem :)

Comment: It's not a problem by itself, but it was redundant information. The title should not contain tags. No worries :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there is no particular 'bad' or 'wrong' way to invoke any (callback) method. You're doing just fine there, also checking for a function.

My only suggestion would be there, not to invoke the function with `.call()`. Unless you  need to pass the current context just call `callback();`. That is, because `.call()` and `.apply()` invokations are up to 30% slower.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the most complete callback functions that i saw. So the answer is no, this is one of the best.